# An inequality $\frac{(1-\lambda)^{2}}{4}\leq m\{x\in [0,1]: |f(x)|\geq \frac{\lambda}{2}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, inequality

In this question $f$ is a Lebesgue measurable function on $[0,1]$ with the property that $\|f\|_{2}=1,\|f\|_{1}=1/2$. I am trying to prove that 
$$
\frac{(1-\lambda)^{2}}{4}\leq m\left\{x\in [0,1]: |f(x)| \geq \frac{\lambda}{2} \right\}\>,
$$
for all $0\leq \lambda \leq1$.

Here, $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.
I think I should use the Chebyshev's inequality to prove this; also I need to split the interval in order to get use $\|f\|_{2}=1,\|f\|_{1}=1/2$, but so far I have no idea about what to do next. This is an old qual problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: With $b = 1/2$,

$$\newcommand{\rd}{\,\mathrm d}\newcommand{\I}[1]{\mathbf 1_{(#1)}}
b = \int |f| \rd x = \int |f| \,\I{|f| \geq \lambda b} \rd x + \int |f| \,\I{|f| < \lambda b} \rd x \>.
$$

Now use Cauchy–Schwarz and monotonicity in appropriate ways.

**Follow-up exercise**: Explain the more general result you've actually just proved replacing $1/2$ with $b \geq 0$ and Lebesgue measure with an arbitrary probability measure.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try now.

Comment: Can you give me some more hint?

Comment: @user: $|f| \I{|f| < \lambda b} < \lambda b$.

Comment: Thanks so much, I got it. It's an elegant proof.Is that right for the probability measure$P(f>b\lambda)\geq b^{2}(1-\lambda)^{2}$?

Comment: @user: You surely meant $\mathbb P(|f| \geq b \lambda)$, but yes, that is correct, under the constraints $\mathbb E |f| \geq b$ and $\mathbb E |f|^2 = 1$. :)

Comment: COOL:) Thanks a lot